# Get values from an RDD

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I created an `RDD` wtih the following format using Scala :

```
Array[(String, (Array[String], Array[String]))]
```

How can I get the list of the `Array[1]` from this `RDD`?

The data for the first data line is:

```
// Array[(String, (Array[String], Array[String]))]
Array(
  (
    966515171418,
    (
      Array(4579848447, 4579848453, 2015-07-29 03:27:28, 44, 1, 1, 966515171418, 966515183263, 420500052424347, 0, 52643, 9, 5067, 5084, 2, 1, 0, 0),
      Array(4579866236, 4579866226, 2015-07-29 04:16:22, 37, 1, 1, 966515171418, 966515183264, 420500052424347, 0, 3083, 9, 5072, 5084, 2, 1, 0, 0)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this (just paste into a `spark-shell`):

```
val a = Array(
  ("966515171418", 
    (Array("4579848447", "4579848453", "2015-07-29 03:27:28", "44", "1", "1", "966515171418", "966515183263", "420500052424347", "0", "52643", "9", "5067", "5084", "2", "1", "0", "0"),
     Array("4579866236", "4579866226", "2015-07-29 04:16:22", "37", "1", "1", "966515171418", "966515183264", "420500052424347", "0",  "3083", "9", "5072", "5084", "2", "1", "0", "0")))
  )

val rdd = sc.makeRDD(a)
```

then you get the first array using

```
scala> rdd.first._2._1
res9: Array[String] = Array(4579848447, 4579848453, 2015-07-29 03:27:28, 44, 1, 1, 966515171418, 966515183263, 420500052424347, 0, 52643, 9, 5067, 5084, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

which means the first row (which is a Tuple2), then the 2nd element of the tuple (which is again a Tuple2), then the 1st element.

Using pattern matching

```
scala> rdd.first match { case (_, (array1, _)) => array1 }
res30: Array[String] = Array(4579848447, 4579848453, 2015-07-29 03:27:28, 44, 1, 1, 966515171418, 966515183263, 420500052424347, 0, 52643, 9, 5067, 5084, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

---

If you want to get it of **all rows**, just use `map()`:

```
scala> rdd.map(_._2._1).collect()
```

which puts the results of all rows into an array.

Another option is to use pattern matching in `map()`:

```
scala> rdd.map { case (_, (array1, _)) => array1 }.collect()
```

Comment: Thanks @Beryllium, your answer is very very close to what I am looking for. I get the following : Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(4579848447, 4579848453, 2015-07-29 03:27:28, 44, 1, 1, 966515171418, 966515183263, 420500052424347, 0, 52643, 9, 5067, 5084, 2, 1, 0, 0)), is there a quick way where I can just get the inside array[String]

Comment: I got it now, just have to flatMap the rdd, and it gives the array. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have updated the answer: If you just want to process the first row, use `first()` (possibly preceeded by `filter` so that really only one row remains). If you want all rows, use `map()`. `flatMap` could be confusing here: consider the case when there are more than one rows in the RDD, and check if `flatMap` still gives you the result you want.